# Distributed cache with WSO2 cep engine

Tags: wso2, hazelcast, siddhi, wso2-cep

General info:

Using tomcat server7.0 with JDK1.7

I have two servers, and I'm using Hazlecat version 3.0 for caching.

My problem is with CEP engine. Using WSO2 engine

I added the following to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.siddhi</groupId>
        <artifactId>siddhi-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0-wso2v1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.siddhi</groupId>
        <artifactId>siddhi-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0-wso2v1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.siddhi</groupId>
        <artifactId>siddhi-query</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0-wso2v1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I set siddhiConfig to DistributedProcessing(true) + set the instanceIdentifier to have the same id of my HazelcastInstance.

Each one of the server has one instance of siddihiManager.

My question is, does the 2 server read from/write to the same cache?

I saw in other places that there is a need to sync between the two servers. Any idea how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you enable [distributed processing](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+CEP+3.0.0+and+3.1.0#ClusteringCEP3.0.0and3.1.0-Distributedcachemodedeployment) in WSO2 CEP(not Siddhi) 310 it will use embedded Hazelcast instances to share events between instances and have a shared state. But due to severe performance issues this approach is discouraged and discontinued in the new [WSO2 CEP](http://wso2.com/products/complex-event-processor/) release.

In the new CEP 4.0.0, [Apache Storm](http://storm.apache.org/) is used to handle distributed processing. You can refer this [sample](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Sample+0501+-+Processing+a+Simple+Filter+Query+with+Apache+Storm+Deployment) and [guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Creating+a+Storm+Based+Distributed+Execution+Plan) on how it is done.

Hope this help even though I did not directly address your initial issue.